# How to embed a video file into an .exe file and use it in my C# program?

Tags: c#, windows, file, exe

I wanna attach a video file into a C# executable and then I want to access it and read the video and display when use runs the .exe file
How can I do that ?
Visual Studio for example embeds Icon of exe files into them so it's possible but how ?

I tried compiling videos into exe files but it wasn't useful because I can't use my C# scripting in them

Comment: There should be plenty of examples of embedded ressources in c#. Here is one: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/22d51c4b-7ceb-487a-91ed-462a6d1e13fd/c-winforms-embed-video-as-resource?forum=winforms

Comment: @PalleDue Do you have any idea, How can I play the video from its stream as I got in the below answer ?
I tried so much but I couldn't do it, DirectX.AudioVideoPlayBack give the exception "the format dll or exe is not supported" I just don't know what to do I tried a lot of libraries

Answer (score 0):

you should embed your video into the c# executable, like below:
[image]
and then use below code to get the video stream:

```
 string resourceName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames().Single(str => str.EndsWith("random.avi")); // get the resource name. it should be assembly name + "random.avi"
using (Stream stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
// now you got the stream, you can bind into your video play controls.
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I have change it to english version @DarkBee

Comment: But how can I play this Stream ? 
The Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback only supports the file as individual on hard drive or URL, not the files that are embedded into exe file

Comment: Then i guess you need to save the resource as a file and play that.